# Create item in 1 list and update in another list with different field types?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, updatelistitems

I am running into errors with a 2010 workflow. I'm doing "Create item in" list #2 with a value from list #1 which is a people picker type field. I can't seem to get the update item in field type right. If list #1 is a people picker, the update to list #2 -- should that be display name? Or string? I feel like I've tried every combo possible with no luck. I keep getting the workflow error "The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information."  (and the variable I'm outputting to is a List Item ID. that's the only option available when I create it)

Create item in:

[image]

Update item in:

[image]

Comment: Do you compare fields from lists to match items that you want to update? If possible post some screenshots

Comment: Thanks Danilo-- yes I did compare them and now the items update, but I still get an error and the workflow cancels with the "Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type." But I don't have any fields as lookup types. That's specifically what that error is referring to, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to people picker, where any workflow cant update any people picker field.

Try to add text field and make it look up column with value of 1st list column.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I will try that, too, Suryakant. Does it make sense, though, that it does update the fields yet I still get the error? Think it would still be because it's people picker?

Comment: I think that will be the only way around it. I actually have 3 lists. From SP 2013 WF #1 to list #2 the fields work great (GUID variable) as People Picker > People Picker show as Display. But from List #2 using WF 2010 to List #3 the only option is List ID variable and I get an error every time. I will try the lookup option. No use trying to get this to Update Item. I've tried every combo. Must have to do with the WF type and variable type?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can create look up column and also write WF to maintain created date of record.